# How create a unique object with two different lists?

Tags: c#, list, windows-phone-8

I have two List <>. Each list contains, however, two different objects. I need to create an object that happy inside two objects of different lists.

```
List1: List <Regions> reg
List2: List <Museums> mus
Object example: object NewObject <reg, mus>
```

is it possible?
I then bring the object created in a new page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a custom object, with two properties:

```
public RegionsMuseums
{
    public List<Regions> Regions {get;set;}
    public List<Museums> Museums { get;set;}

    public RegionsMuseums(List<Regions> regions,  List<Museums> museums)
    {
        Regions = reg;
        Museums = mu;
    }
}
```

Then you could create an instance of this object:

```
var obj = new RegionsMuseums(reg, mus);
```

where `reg` and `mus` are the regions and museums lists respectively you have.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use a Tuple

```
reg.Zip(mus, (r,m) => Tuple.Create(r,m)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a compound wrapper object and either use [object initializer syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) or provide a constructor that takes the two collections as arguments.

```
public class CompoundObject
{
    public List<Regions> Regions { get; set; }
    public List<Museums> Museums { get; set; }
}

var example = new CompoundObject { Regions = reg, Museums = mus };
```

OR

```
public class CompoundObject
{
    public List<Regions> Regions { get; set; }
    public List<Museums> Museums { get; set; }

    public CompoundObject(List<Regions> regions, List<Museums> museums)
    {
        Regions = regions;
        Museums = Museums;
    }
}

var example = new CompoundObject(reg, mus);
```

Comment: very clean assuming the `OP` knows how to understand, also  @Christos is just as nice and is valid too